# Algolia Sort Without Indexing Replicas

Tags: ranking, algolia

Can we set sorting/ranking criteria for Algolia results without need to setSettings for a single index with each request being set with different sorting criteria as in code below and without setting new index replicas. ?

return Observable.from(
            index.setSettings({'customRanking': [
                sort_field,
            ],
                'ranking': [ "custom" ]
            }).then(function(){
                return index.search({query: queryParams.query,filters:filteredQuery,hitsPerPage:queryParams.perpage,page:queryParams.page})
            })
        )

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately custom ranking is not a 'query time' parameter meaning that you cannot override your configuration during the query to modify the index answer. A Different custom ranking needs a replica.